# Modal window is empty

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, simplemodal

If I try in the debugger something as simple as

```
a=$.modal("<div><h1>SimpleModal</h1></div>");
```

for a page where I loaded jquery 1.8.3 and simplemodal 1.4.3 (latest) and correct css, I have a modal window that pops up but it contains nothing.
This is the case in Chrome but not in Firefox. No clue why...

Comment: works fine here in chrome http://jsfiddle.net/cCYFq/

Comment: Well if I go back and use jquery 1.7.2, it works fine again (although there is an ugly horizontal scroll bar)...

Comment: I agree with Spontifixus. I tried to reproduce it within JSFiddle by adding all JS libs and it all works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/gTwH3/ Very confusing :/ So I guess we can close this discussion.